# how to call static method inside non static method through instance

Tags: c#, static, instance

I understand that we could use the class name.method but I was wondering if there was a way to do it through an instance. Can you provide me an example also. The reason I'm asking is because my professor said:

> You MUST invoke the extension method using calls that use the static
>   call form and the instance call form

Comment: No, you can't do that. Why would you want to anyway?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque  my professor in his directions said: You MUST invoke the extension method using calls that use the static call form
 and the instance call form

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  When you have a static property in a class there is only once instance of the property in the class that all instances of the class share.

Comment: @jdweng maybe I misunderstood my professor directions when he said "You MUST invoke the extension method using calls that use the static call form and the instance call form". In any case I'll add that direction to my description so people know im not that crazy

Comment: @Brogrammer wait... "extension method"? that's easy, then! I'll edit my answer to show that - you didn't say it was an extension method!

Comment: When passing data between two forms you must use an instance of the form.  See my two form example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng but nothing is static..

Comment: That is correct.  What the teach meant to say is you can't use static object to get data between processes.  The static object have to be passed in the parameter list.  So tasks, events, and forms are run as separate processes and the data must be passed in the parameter list.

Comment: @jdweng wait... who mentioned processes? I think you're just making things unnecessarily confusing now... (also: forms, events and tasks are not separate processes)

Comment: @MarcGravell Your answer really helped I gave it +1 with green check!

Comment: I'm explaining the real issue and it is not confusing.  The real issue is to prevent cross threading of processes static object cannot be shared between processes.  And threads, events, and forms are separate processes.  Marc your answer if very poor and I down graded it because it has nothing to do with the teachers response "form and the instance call form".  My two form project shows how to call forms by an instance.

Comment: @jdweng I believe you have misunderstood the Q. This has *absolutely nothing* to do with threads or cross threading; not "windows forms", and nothing to do with processes. Whatsoever, categorically. There are some cases where instances have thread-affinity (as with windows forms), but *that isn't what we're talking about here*. When OP uses the word "form", they don't mean "windows forms"; they mean "mechanism", "syntax". They're talking about the two ways (two "forms") of calling extension methods - via the explicit static syntax (static form), and the instance-style syntax (instance form).

Comment: Still what I said is accurate and applicable.  You cannot use the static instance form to send between processes.

Comment: @jdweng **nobody is talking about processes**; and no, it isn't even **remotely** applicable to the topic, and when you are talking about threads, forms and processes interchangeably, it is impossible to comment on accuracy. You made a mistake in terms of what the question was about; that's OK - everyone does that; I do that. The correct thing to do is to go "oh yeah, oops! my bad, thanks".

Comment: It is a good answer.

Comment: @jdweng it wasn't an answer (it was a comment), and no: it was not - IMO - good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the edit that this is talking about *extension* methods, then it becomes easier!

With the same example as below:

```
bool hasValue1 = s.HasValue(); // use the instance syntax
bool hasValue2 = StringExtensions.HasValue(s); // use the static syntax
```

Note that these are 100% identical; once compiled to IL you cannot determine which form was used.

---

Short answer: "no", per CS0176:

> CS0176    Member '{name}' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Slightly longer answer: if you *really* want to do that, maybe extension methods are what you are looking for; for example:

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool HasValue(this string value)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = /* some string or null reference */
        bool hasValue = s.HasValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I try making string s and then doing s."static method class" saying the string does not contain the definition for my static method and no extension method.

Comment: @Brogrammer indeed - you need to create the extension method, which is what I do in the `StringExtensions` class in the example - the `this` modifier before the first parameter denotes an extension method. Perhaps it would be clearer if I changed the method name in my example - I'll do that now...

Comment: @Brogrammer ...done - I've reversed (`!`) the return value and changed the extension method to be `HasValue`